# Why does Tekka say "where" while Kylo asked "why" he has come?

Tags: analysis, star-wars, the-force-awakens

These are some quotes from *Star Wars​: The Force Awakens*:

> Kylo Ren : Look how old you've become.
>
> Lor San Tekka : Something far worse has happened to you.
>
> Kylo Ren : You know what I've come for.
>
> Lor San Tekka : I know where you come from, before you called yourself "Kylo Ren".

Why does Lor respond "where you come from" whereas he was supposed to confirm to "what I've come from"?

Comment: This comes across more as an English Language comprehension question. Kylo isn't asking a question, he's making a statement. Same for Lor.

Comment: "what I've come from" is literally not what was said in the quote you yourself posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tekka is referring to Kylo Ren's heritage, being the son of Han Solo & Princess/General Leia, and nephew of Luke Skywalker.

"Where" in this instance is not about a location, but of character and substance of his family's legacy. Tekka, not directly responding to Kylo Ren's statement, instead takes a shot back at Kylo Ren implying that Kylo Ren is fooling himself, insinuating that Kylo Ren is pretending to be something he is not.

To paraphrase Tekka: *It doesn't matter what you think/say you want, because I know whom you really are.*

One has to remember that Lorr San Tekka is also a member of the Church of the Force, whom believe in the practices and restoration of the Jedi Order.

A good chunk of the sequel trilogy is debating if there is redemption for Kylo Ren and/or if Kylo Ren's philosophy has any justification. This scene just plays on the contention of such a debate.